# Problem with SQL Server smalldatetime insert query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, insert

I have the field:

```
APP_DATE (smalldatetime)
```

I'm doing this query:

```
INSERT INTO table (TYPE, CODE, APP_DATE, DATE) VALUES ('APP', '123', '02/10/2010 12.30', GETDATE())
```

It fails:

```
Msg 296, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Conversion from datatype char to smalldatetime generated a value not between the interval of valid values.
Instruction has been interrupted.

(0 row(s) affected)
```

What am I doing wrong? It appears to me as the correct format for the field..

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `:` in your time instead of `.`. Then it will insert fine.

Comment: Ah, I have SQL Server 2005. Maybe that's the problem. Try changing the format of the date, maybe '2010-19-02 16:28' ? Or perhaps you've got the wrong locale settings, does it think 19 is the month?

Answer (score 8):

Can you try to use the [ISO-8601 date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS) - this will work always on SQL Server - regardless of your regional and locale settings:

```
INSERT INTO table (TYPE, CODE, APP_DATE, DATE) 
VALUES ('APP', '123', '20100210 12:30:00', GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

The date time format isn't correct; the year should be 4 digit (otherwise it is ambiguous) and the time separator should be a colon.

2003/01/22 22:31 will work. see [this article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2197931/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Two---Displaying-Dates-and-Times-in-Different-Formats.htm).

Answer (score 1):

insert into yourTable(yourSmallDateTimeColumn) values('1900-01-01 11:45:23');//format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the time element in the field SQL Server will default it to 00:00:00 for you if you just send in '02/10/2010' If you need the time element then your format for the time is wrong in your example and it should be something like this - 
'02/10/2010 12:31:00'

Answer (score 0):

at PHP you have function date, you can write the format you want inside
like this example

```
$smallDateAndTime =date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

Comment: Please explain your solution in a bit more detail.